# Refactoring big if else stament in C# code

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have four of this really long if-else code. How can I refactor this code?

```
if (objectcameraangle > 140)
{
  if (Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2) > 0.5)
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((scx / 10000), scy / 10000, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((scx / 800), scy / 800, 0);
  }
}
else if (objectcameraangle < 35)
{
  if (Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2) > 0.5)
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((-scx / 10000), scy / 10000, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((-scx / 800), scy / 800, 0);
  }
}
else if (objectcameraangle > 35 && objectcameraangle < 140 && signed > 0)
{
  if (Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2) > 0.5)
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(0, scy / 10000, (-scx / 10000));
  }
  else
  {
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(0, scy / 800, (-scx / 800));
  }
}
```

How I can rewrite it to something more nice . Trying to learn here something new . Thanks for help.

Comment: Write a method called by each if block parameterized with the different values to `Translate`?

Comment: Isn't it better to create single call to `Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2)`. Say `distance = Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2);` & use `distance` in every `if` condition?

Comment: @harrysrangal I think you can go even further than that (e.g. `var denominator = (Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2) > 0.5 ? 10000 : 800);`).  Check my suggested answer below for an example.

Comment: @wildbeast is that `(-scx / 1000)` in the final `if...else` block correct?  Or should it be `(-scx / 10000)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var distance = Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2);
var divisor = distance > 0.5 ? 10000 : 800;

var scx2 = scx / divisor;
var scy2 = scy / divisor;

if (objectcameraangle < 35)
{
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(-scx2, scy2, 0);
}
else if (objectcameraangle < 140)
{
    if (signed > 0)
        Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(0, scy2, -scx2);
}
else
{
    Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(scx2, scy2, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of C# (8.0+ I think?), you can try something like this:

```
var denominator = (Vector3.Distance(joint1, joint2) > 0.5 ? 10000 : 800);

switch (true) {
    case var _ when objectcameraangle > 140:
        Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((scx / denominator), scy / denominator, 0);
        break;
    case var _ when objectcameraangle < 35:
        Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate((-scx / denominator), scy / denominator, 0);
        break;
    case var _ when objectcameraangle > 35 && objectcameraangle < 140 && signed > 0:
        Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate(0, scy / denominator, (-scx / denominator));
        break;
}
```

Hopefully that compiles... I don't have all of your objects available, obviously, so I couldn't check myself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see two things:

- Almost all of that code is for all intents and purposes, simply assigning 4 different variables, and
- There are fall-through/no-op conditions: When `scx` is exactly `35` or `140`, or `signed` is non-positive.

I would isolate the assignment of each variable and invoke the `Translate()` method at the end, thus:

```
int angle = objectcameraangle // because, too many letters (and runtogetherwords)

int d = Vector3Distance > 0.5
      ? 10000
      :   800
      ;
int? x = angle > 140                              ?   scx / d
       : angle <  35                              ? - scx / d
       : angle >  35 && angle < 140 && signed > 0 ? 0
       : null // TODO what happens when objectcameraangle is exactly 35 or 140, or is signed <= 0?
       ;
int? y = angle > 140                              ?   scy / d
       : angle <  35                              ?   scy / d
       : angle >  35 && angle < 140 && signed > 0 ?   scy / d
       : null // TODO what happens when objectcameraangle is exactly 35 or 140, or is signed <= 0?
       ;
int? z = angle > 140 ? 0
       : angle <  35 ? 0
       : angle >  35 && angle < 140 && signed > 0 ? - scx / d
       : null // TODO what happens when objectcameraangle is exactly 35 or 140, or is signed <= 0?
       ;

// Wrapped in a guard clause to protect against the fall-through condition(s) noted above
if ( x != null && y != null && z != null ) {
  Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate( x, y, z );
}
```

You could then extract the logic for each of the 4 variable assignments out to individual methods, making them simple and easily testable. That would give you something like this:

```
static int SelectDistance( double v3Distance )
{
  return Vector3Distance > 0.5
       ? 10000
       :   800
       ;
}

static int SelectValue( angle int , signed int, v1 int, v2 int , v3 int , v4 int)
{
  return angle > 140                             ? v1
       : angle <  35                             ? v2
       : angle >  35 && angle < 140 && signe > 0 ? v3
       :                                           v4
       ;
}
.
.
.
int  angle = objectcameraangle // because, too many letters (and runtogetherwords)

int  d = SelectDistance( Vector3Distance );
int? x = SelectValue( angle, signed, scx/d, -scx/d,      0, null );
int? y = SelectValue( angle, signed, scy/d,  scy/d,  scy/d, null );
int? z = SelectValue( angle, signed,     0,      0, -scx/d, null );

// Wrapped in a guard clause to protect against the fall-through condition(s) noted above
if ( x != null && y != null && z != null ) {
  Rfootikcontroller.transform.Translate( x, y, z );
}
```